# Checking for a special character / regular expression in an object in R

Tags: regex, r, object, if-statement

How will one check if an object has special character in R.  I have the following object j. I want to have an if statement that checks if j has a special character. I am not getting it right. I tried using the grep but doesn't work.

```
j <- c(>1080)

if(grep('>',j)){
 do this
} else do that
```

Comment: By special characters what do you mean ? punctuation ? or everything expect words and numbers ?

Comment: Even your first line isn't syntactically correct.  Was that supposed to be a string?  I didn't downvote though since your code looks like it should be a poem (although it's a poem with horrible grammar).

Comment: '>' is referred to as punctuation. I only want to find if the object has '>' (greater than) sign in it

Comment: pardon my english. English is not my native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape special characters in general when you use regular expressions.

Like this

```
strings <- c("add>dff", "edrf", "133", ">", "12>", "12a?")
grep("\\>", strings, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "add>dff" ">"       "12>"
```

You can also use `grepl` to test for the presence of this sign

```
grepl("\\>", strings, perl = TRUE)
## [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But then how will we check if the object has ">" greater than sign

Comment: how will it be interpreted as a logic